# Multiple classes to one table JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Is it possible to have different classes being loaded depending on the value of the field? For each of these classes there would be a corresponding row in a database, and can be discerned by "type" field. They would all share the same interface (apply).

Comment: You're basically describing the SINGLE_TABLE entity inheritance strategy. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e3356. I'm not sure this is the right approach, though. Your entity could just be a factory that would use its type field to create an instance of an Apply interface.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. I already abandoned this idea, have to think of something else..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can achieve this with JPA quite easily. Assume you have a "location" table and you can different rows for different types of locations such as StoreLocation and CustomerLocation for example. Then we can model this in JPA entities like below.

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "name of column you need to filter with")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class LocationEntity {

}
```

Then we can have other more specific tables

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("STORE") // set the value of the column for store location rows
public class StoreLocationEntity extends LocationEntity {

}
```

and another one

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("CUSTOMER") // set the value of the column for customer location rows
public class CustomerLocationEntity extends LocationEntity {

}
```

Hope this example will help you to get started.